# Google Analytics goal after user authentication email link clicked

Tags: google-analytics

I am measuring the goal of user registration using Google Analytics.

After registering, users need to authenticate their email by clicking on a link that they are emailed (this is just standard email authentication practice).

I consider the clicked link to be a user registration and this is the goal I set up on Google Analytics via the url (ie: destination goal).

From my GA data, I noticed that, many times, the source/medium of said goal is "direct" when it should in fact be something else (I know that it should be something else because the landing page is the destination page that I set for the goal, which is not a page that a user can access as a first page via normal use).

I suspect that a lot of users, when opening the authentication email and clicking on the link, have their device automatically open the link in a different browser from the one they were using before, thus causing it to be counted as a "new user" in GA.

To fix this issue, I am considering using [Linker](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker) to append the client ID to the link that is emailed in the email authentication.

Since I would imagine this is a common issue, I wanted to ask if this is the simplest fix for this issue I'm experiencing. Is there a simpler fix that I'm missing?

Comment: Why not use the URL Builder and add the link to the button?

Comment: It's dynamic, users can be coming from all different sources. Which link would I be adding to the button?

Comment: I see, but you can filter through campaign, for example. But I understand the tracking issue

Comment: I'm not following. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: [This](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/) You can set the variables accordingly. It's an idea.

Comment: That just dictates the campaign, etc. that is credited in GA. That does not solve the issue I described. Ie: GA will still mark that user as a "new user" therefore, credit will not be given to that user's actual source/medium.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184174/discussion-between-tico-and-theyuv).

Comment: Do you use utm tags in link form email? And what source/medium do you expect for goals?

Comment: No, no utm tags, I want it to be a continuation of the user's session (or at least be attributed to the same client).